# Docker hub jhipster-registry not accessible on port 8761

Tags: microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I have recently started exploring the microservice architecture using jhipster and was trying to install and run the jhipster-registry from docker hub. Docker shows that the registry is running, but I am unable to access it on port 8761.

Pulled the image with `docker pull jhipster/jhipster-registry`

Started the container with `docker run --name jhipster-registry -d jhipster/jhipster-registry`

Here's a snapshot of what `docker container ls` returns:

[image: docker container ls]

Am I missing something over here?

Answer (score 2):

You are starting the JHipster Registry container, but you aren't exposing the port.

You can expose a port by passing [the port flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) `-p 8761:8761` which will enable you to connect to it via `localhost:8761` or `127.0.0.1:8761` in a browser.

You may need to configure some environment variables for the JHipster Registry to start correctly.  These may depend on your generated app's options, such as authentication type. For convenience JHipster apps come with a [`docker-compose.yml` file](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-gateway/blob/9f22a474227cc19c629fef29d9e5d9fedd0cdb3c/src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml). You can start it with `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml up`, [as documented](https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/#using-docker).